# European RoHS directive - is it a nonsense?

Tags: rohs

I live in European Union. We have RoHS directive here.

> Each European Union member state will adopt its own enforcement and
>   implementation policies using the directive as a guide.
>
> RoHS is often referred to (inaccurately) as the 'lead-free directive',
>   but it restricts the use of the following six substances:
>
> - Lead (Pb)
> - Mercury (Hg)
> - Cadmium (Cd)
> - Hexavalent chromium (Cr6+)
> - Polybrominated biphenyls (PBB)
> - Polybrominated diphenyl ether (PBDE)

(from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_of_Hazardous_Substances_Directive))

There are many things, where lead, mercury and cadmium is used.

- car battery - 20kg of lead that "can be recycled" - yea, right...
- fishing weight (fishing sinker) - pure lead - a lot of these things end it's life in rivers and lakes and nobody cares about recycling
- Ni-Cd batteries in some of battery powered tools
- mercury in mass produced fluorescent lamps (EU banned traditional bulbs) - nobody cares, many people just throw them into trash

And I can't use normal resistors in my product because they contain more than 0.1% of lead? What kind of nonsense is this?

I've read directive, I know it allows exeptions... but I think these exeptions make whole directive dumb. This is just a problem for small electronics manufacturers...

Comment: And what is the question? I think you might be right, I never clashed with such problems because I'm still a kiddo, but about the type of discussion you want to have I'd say: post it in a forum. -1.

Comment: If you're involved in manufacturing of electronics to some extent you know that ROHS is a huge pain in the A$$. I think the idea is good but no one really thought things through because many times manufacturers are left with all kind of production issues as parts and processes are banned and solving the issues might end up in R&D departments - the costs that pile up for these adjustments can be huge. If things were better planned the whole thing would take longer and allow alternatives to be slowly integrated into production. BTW - car batteries do get recycled.

Comment: @user34920: This really depends on what kind of production you're involved with. As a system integrator or assembler it's a giant PITA because you are dependent on *all* your suppliers having RoHS alternatives. As a component or bulk manufacturer, it's easy peasy. However, this isn't really an issue anymore. RoHS has been with us for many years now and it is rare to find non-compliant suppliers at all.

Comment: @user36129 - I worked for a large medical company, and as you might be aware, production was not ROHS mandatory until a short time ago (ROHS2). Some of the components used were custom made (high gain ultra low noise op amps and some other micro coils) and they started to work on compliance about 3 years ago, I have no idea how things turned out but it was consuming a lot of time back then and this while all the custom components were not designed in house.

Comment: While I understand that this is a frustrating regulation for designers of electronics, EE.SE is not the place to have a conversation about it. There's no real question here, and even if there were, it would relate to politics, economics and environmental issues, not electronics design.

Comment: Cr6+ is very nasty stuff and should indeed be avoided if possible. The rest isn't particularly friendly either.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are misunderstanding this directive, and putting it into an extreme case of 'if any of substance X is allowed, it doesn't work'. Here's what it's for and why it exists the way it does.

RoHS means *Reduction* of Hazardous Substances. Not elimination. The directive has been put in place to reduce a very large list of hazardous substances as defined by both the EU and member states, to reduce or eliminate the impact of waste material on the environment when old electronics eventually get scrapped, as well as to protect (inter)national health like for instance scrap recovery workers in third-world countries who deal with the waste stream from developed countries.

The directive implicitly forbids the use of any substance on the list when a cost-effective, functionally equivalent non-hazardous replacement exists. This is basically the bulk of RoHS' effectiveness: new production is not using dangerous materials anymore. Also, in most member states companies are compelled to discontinue old production in favor of new, RoHS-compliant production by e.g. lowering waste taxes and offering subsidies if the production volume is large enough.

Now, this would all be fine if all toxic and dangerous chemicals could be entirely avoided at all times, but sometimes no functional alternatives exist. Lead-acid batteries are a good example of something that is functionally very hard to replace. They have historically offered a large cost benefit and like e.g. steel they have extremely high recycling rates. As lead is also practically inert in a waste dump it has been deemed this type of battery can have an exemption.

Same goes for fluorescent lighting. There's literally no replacement for mercury; you need it for the internal UV emission. In this case RoHS has caused manufacturers to find ways to drastically decrease the required amount of mercury (again, *reduction*, not elimination) and explore ways to reduce the need for mercury by improving efficacy (e.g. through improved phosphors).

Ni-Cd doesn't exist in production anymore except for a few very specific applications, e.g. satellites and scientific equipment. NiCd batteries were used in cordless drills for a while because of the cost benefit, but this is not allowed anymore or taxed heavily depending on where you live.

The way we live in developed countries, there's no hope of eliminating environment-destroying toxins. RoHS is one of the ways to reduce the use of these substances and even though it hasn't been in place for too long, it seems to be working.

As for your comment on 'creating problems for small electronics manufacturers' - it seems like the opposite is the case. Especially in the early days of RoHS, small manufacturers were booming as they were the only ones to be able to quickly turn around production towards RoHS alternatives, whereas large companies were much slower.

Comment: Directive says "Restriction" not "Reduction"...

Comment: Ugh... that's what happens when I write this stuff after a long night. Yes, it doesn't really change the premise of my answer but you are right.

Answer (score 3):

Notes: Intended to be read in conjunction with other answers:

Whether it is notionally "a nonsense" or not is irrelevant to the reality of manufacturing. If you want to sell in Europe and most other countries the product **MUST** be ROHS compliant. There is nothing the average manufacturer can do about changing things. It would be a nonsense to not comply.

Note that an "XRF gun" (XRAY fluorescence) will detect non compliance of components in a a sealed product in seconds.   [XRF - how it works](http://www.niton.com/en/portable-xrf-technology/how-xrf-works)
[ROHS testing](http://www.skyrayxrf.com/electronics-rohs.php)
[XRF screening](http://www.niton.com/en/rohs-compliance-hi-rel)

Resistors below a specified % of lead are functionally or formally exempt. If COTS SMD resistors are the only component that the XRF gun locates then your product will very probably pass.

All Europe has state mandated ROHS.
USA has no Federal requirement but California requires ROHS compliance and other states are in the process of introducing it.
[ROHS USA](http://www.skyrayxrf.com/California-RoHS.php)

NiCd batteries are generally frowned on even when notionally allowed.

Mercury levels in modern tube and CFL fluorescent lights are extremely low by traditional standards. It can be shown that for incandescent and fluorescent lighting of equal light output, if the additional energy required to power the incandescent bulb is supplied by coal powered stations then the extra mercury liberated in coal ash from the power station stack will exceed the amount in the equivalent fluorescent tube. And the power station mercury will be distributed in the worst case manner - from a high stack into a wind stream and as a vapour or very finely divided.

Lead acid batteries have high scrap value. Most would not get to garbage disposal sites and any formal garbage processing site would formally or informally salvage them as much as possible, probably for their scrap value alone, quite apart from lead contamination issues.

Metallic bulk lead is relatively benign. Sucking solder is far from recommended but probably not vastly bad compared to some other materials. Lead in compounds which can vaporise or flake as fine powder or in forms which are soluble or somewhat soluble are much more likely to be hazardous. The dangers of lead paint flakes to children and maintenance workers is extremely well documented.

There appears to be a statistically significant correlation between the use of tetraethyl lead in petrol and some serious health conditions. While noting the standard correlation <> causation warning, you'd be extremely brave and stupid to not err on the side of caution with such products.

Getting the compounds out of the environment seems wise. I'm not so sure of the merits of eliminating metallic lead and eg lead solder - but the battle has been fought long ago  and cannot now be refought.